# How to extract/open game obb files in windows PC?

Tags: android, zip, extract, apk-expansion-files

Can anyone suggest me any tool to extract/open game obb files in windows PC? I want to learn to customize the look and feel of the game. The game data is compressed with pkzip compression.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OBB files are "Opaque binary blobs". As the name suggests, there is no standard format. The game developer can use them in whatever way they wish.

Many game developers treat them as zip files, so renaming them as .zip might get you somewhere. But beyond that, there is no standard, it will vary from game to game.

Comment: I was able to do it with QUICKBMS with CPK script

Answer (score 0):

As said by [Nick Fortescue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55219028/17947699)

But once you know the game engine, you can try to decode it in that particular engine. For example if a game is made in Unity Engine, you can try to decode that files in unity engine...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).